# need to ask person how many days in the selected month and show the user how many days and are in that month with leap year(java)

Tags: java

i said it all in title but i need mainly the last section help i cant get the adding correctly it shows year-double  and day in the system.out.printf as normal numbers

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class lab 
{
public static void main(String []args)
{

int day=0;

String month=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"what month is it").substring(0,3);


if (month=="jan")
{
day=31;
}
if (month=="feb")
{
day=28;
}
if(month=="mar")
{
day=31;
}
if(month=="apr")
 {
day=30;
}
if(month=="may")
{
day=31; 
}
if(month=="jun")
{
day=30;
}
if(month=="jul")
{
day=31;
}
if(month=="aug")
{
day=31; 
}
if(month=="sep")
{
day=30;
}
if(month=="oct")
{
day=31;
}
if(month=="nov")
{
day=30;
}
if(month=="dec")
{
day=31;
}
String yearString=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("what year is it");

double yeardouble=Double.parseDouble(yearString);
if(yeardouble % 4==0)
{
yeardouble=1;
}
else 


yeardouble=0;





double answer = yeardouble + day;


System.out.printf( "theres "+ day + " days in"+ answer );




}
}
```

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare Strings. Use the equals method instead.

Comment: You should clean up your code sample formatting, and explain better what the problem is. What output do you expect to get, and what are you getting instead? It's also helpful to make a code sample without user input/output using some hardcoded example data.

Answer (score 1):

Don't compare Strings using `==`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that == checks if the two *objects* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.  So instead of

```
if (fu == "bar") {
  // do something
}
```

do,

```
if ("bar".equals(fu)) {
  // do something
}
```

or,

```
if ("bar".equalsIgnoreCase(fu)) {
  // do something
}
```